# Android emulator (adb devices -l) unauthorized error

Tags: android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools, avd-manager

**Requirement**

Share all the android virtual devices (AVD) across multiple instances. So that, an AVD can be started from any instance.

**Setup**

[image: android emulator setup]

- I have multiple instances where the Android Sdk are donwloaded
- Location of `.android` is put in a separate HDD, wherein all the AVD devices lies

**Problem**

> I am able to create avd from an instance and also able to start avd from that particular instance only.
> But when I try to start avd from another instance, it gives the following unauthorized error

Command: `adb devices -l`

[image: adb unauthorized error]

**Solutions Tried**

These are the solutions that I tried but it didn't work.

- Tried to kill adb server and start again, `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`
- Tried generating a new adbKey using `adb pubkey ~/.android/adbkey > ~/.android/adbkey.pub` and replacing it with old ones.

**Commands**

- To create the emulator

```sh
avdmanager create avd --name test -b google_apis/x86 -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86" --device "pixel"
```

- To start the emulator

```sh
emulator -avd test -gpu swiftshader_indirect -show-kernel -snapshot test -port 5542
```